# Why is my 2-d list holding a maximum of 2 items

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, pygame, pickle

I have made a game using python and pygame and i have just got around to trying to do things with saving times and names. However when there is 2 items in the list the first items save and works fine but the seconds items gets overwritten every time i complete the game.

```
try:
    openFile = open("times.txt", "rb")
    runTimes = pickle.load(openFile)
    runTimes.append([g.name, g.count])
    openFile.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    runTimes = []
    runTimes.append([g.name, g.count])
    openFile = open("times.txt", "wb")
    pickle.dump(runTimes, openFile)
    openFile.close()

if len(runTimes) > 1:
    print(runTimes)
```

Run 1 = Nothing happens

Run 2

```
[['Undefined', 7.5], ['Undefined', 8.3]]
```

Run 3

```
[['Undefined', 7.5], ['Undefined', 7.5]]
```

Comment: What is `g`? Where is it initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you forget to `pickle.dump` also when the `try:` block succeeds to update your file? This is probably what you want:

```
try:
    openFile = open("times.txt", "rb")
    runTimes = pickle.load(openFile)
    openFile.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    runTimes = []

runTimes.append([g.name, g.count])
openFile = open("times.txt", "wb")
pickle.dump(runTimes, openFile)
openFile.close()

if len(runTimes) > 1:
    print(runTimes)
```